# Blacklist countries in Google Load Balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to blacklist countries in Google Cloud Load Balancer?

Since GDPR, we do not want to send EU request in some of the services. If we don't want to serve some of the services to some countries, how can we block them?

Answer (score 0):

GCP LB provides [User-defined request headers](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#user-defined-request-headers). You can define {client_region} variable for your custom header and redirect your EU users to your "We hate GDPR" page based on this header.